Оборот с «прежде чем...» в середине предложения
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с пунктуацией в этом предложении:
"Она стояла во дворе и()прежде()чем зайти в дом()решила позвонить другу".
Для сравнения я попыталась заменить "прежде чем" на другую конструкцию:
"Она стояла во дворе и перед тем, как зайти в дом, решила позвонить другу" (здесь пунктуация кажется более очевидной, но чем больше думаю, тем больше сомневаюсь).
В изначальном предложении запятые расставляются по такому же принципу?
"Она стояла во дворе и прежде, чем зайти в дом, решила позвонить другу".
Или нет?
Спасибо.

Одной запятой достаточно.
Она стояла во дворе и, прежде чем зайти в дом, решила позвонить другу.


Спасибо за помощь!
